# How do I edit the posted "by" and "on" in the post meta

Tags: post-meta

I just want to rename "by" and "on" the author name and date is changed already.
I have tried many plugins but couldnt find a way to do this. if it is something to do with editting php, please tell me the exact file and location and the line which I hav to edit. Please assist me..

Comment: This depends on your theme. Its developer should be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The text that is output in the author name/date (called 'post meta') is controlled by your theme.

If you want to change that, it's best to create a Child Theme, then copy the template from the main theme to your Child Theme folder and edit that. (Never edit the theme files directly, as any changes you make will get overwritten with a theme update.)

You'll need to find the exact location in your theme file yourself; every theme is different. Take a look at how theme hierarchy works: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ to determine which theme file is being used for your posts.

Help on Child Themes here https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes .  The googles have tons of info on both subjects.